# Manual summary separator becomes HUGOMORE42 with blogdown

Tags: hugo, blogdown

I just updated my version of hugo to 0.53 (from a rather old 0.21) and one of the consequences of the update is that string

```
<!--more-->
```

that was previously used for identifying the end of the blog post summary is now replaced with the string `HUGOMORE42`. Also, the summary end is not correctly triggered.

Can anyone point me in a direction to fix this? If I downgrade to an earlier version of HUGO then the problem disappears, so I'm guessing it is an identifier that was changed along the way.

I tried with my old version of the default `hugo-lithium-theme` and with another theme. It *might* be a problem with the theme, but if that is the case where can I fix that? (I have various local modifications of the theme in layouts that might be the culprits).

Googling `HUGOMORE42` yield quite a number of webpages that appear to have the same problem so that is not that useful.

Comment: Did you come across this?https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/how-to-output-more-as-string/7722/2

Comment: @AadityaMaheshwari yes but that is another problem. They want the literal string `<!--more-->` to appear on the page without being rendered. I want it to be rendered and interpreted correctly

Comment: Are you using hugo extended?

Comment: @AadityaMaheshwari I not entirely sure exactly what that means but the version prints `Hugo Static Site Generator v0.53/extended darwin/amd64 BuildDate: unknown` so I guess that is a **yes**. It was the version of Hugo installed by `blogdown::install_hugo()`

Comment: That is correct. You are using extended variant of Hugo; which is good. Are you also using something called 'Org mode'?

Comment: @AadityaMaheshwari Nope. Writing everything in Rmarkdown